# How to Start JBOSS AS 7 without deploying already deployed webapps

Tags: jboss7.x

Is there a way to Start JBOSS AS 7 without deploying already deployed  webapps
 Like Tomcat

Comment: What is it you're trying to do specifically? You cat start the server in `--admin-only` mode which will give you admin access if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi James, when I'm starting  the server ,it deploys  all web apps present in the standalone\deployments folder.Im asking whether we can start the server without redeploying them or not..

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by redeploy. They will be deployed every time the server starts. You can disable the `deployment-scanner`, but that means when you start the server none of the deployments will be deployed.

Comment: Thanks @JamesR.Perkins, I  disabled the deployment-scanner.Now ,No wars are deployed during startup

Comment: @KKR, Answers should not be in comments, Please add this answer suggested in the answer field with credits and accept the solution if you are satisfied.